# Asserting for presence of an uploaded file in Django

Tags: django, django-file-upload

Say I have a model containing a `FileField` and I have just created an object, and hence have a file stored to a particular location. How would I assert the file is stored in there?

For my case I have `MEDIA_ROOT='/path/to/my/files/'` in my `settings.py` and indeed the files do get stored there but I want to have it "officially" tested and verified.

What I now have is;

```
uploaded_file = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/test_audio.mp3'
assert os.path.exists(uploaded_file)
```

The problem here is that as Django doesn't delete the stored file from the location as with the case of models after testing, the file get stored with a name change after the first test. I'll have to manually delete the file before every test. Below is my test with the present assert statement

```
class TestAudioFileManagement(TestCase):
def test_audio_upload(self):
    """
    Tests uploading of audio
    """
    User.objects.create_user(username="somename",
                        password="somepassword")
    self.client.login(username="somename",
                      password="somepassword")
    name = "somename"
    audio_file = SimpleUploadedFile(
        'test_audio.mp3', 
        open('/home/afzalsh/works/openradio/test_files/test_audio.mp3','rb').read(),
        content_type='audio'
    )
    self.client.post(reverse('actual_upload_audio'),
                     {'name':name,
                      'audio_file':audio_file})
    uploaded_file = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/test_audio.mp3'
    assert os.path.exists(uploaded_file)
```

A solution anyone?

Comment: Remove it at the end of the test with `os.remove(uploaded_file)`

Comment: Novice me! Please have it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it at the end of the test with `os.remove(uploaded_file)`